# Primefaces Sheet How to Remove Row Resize Functionality

Tags: handsontable, primefaces-extensions

I have sheet which uses handsontable if i scroll table to right Only frozen columns stayed with same colwidth and height. And other columns width and height changing even if i set colwidth to them.
In my javascript i tried like below but it didnt do anything or show any error on browser console or ide console.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

            const $hot = PF('sheetWidget').ht;
          
            $hot.updateSettings({

                rowHeights(index) {
                    return (index + 1) * 20;
                },
                manualRowResize: true,
            });
            $hot.render();
}
```

I think i should use beforeRowResize function and return false but tried that and no effect too.

My sheet code:

```
<pe:sheet id="someSheet" widgetVar="sheetWidget"
              value="#{ManagedBean.materials}" var="material"
              rowKey="#{material.id}" showRowHeaders="true" extender="sheetExtender" height="300"
              sortBy="#{material.id}" fixedCols="3" sortOrder="ascending"
              stretchH="all" resizableCols="true" readOnly="false">

    
        <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Material Number"
                        readOnly="true"
                        value="#{material.materialNumber}"
        />

        <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Material Description (Imperial)"
                        readOnly="true" colWidth="250"
                        value="#{material.imperialDescription}"
        />

        <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Material Description (Metric)"
                        readOnly="true" colWidth="250"
                        value="#{material.metricDescription}"
        />

        <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Due Date"
                        value="#{material.dueDate}" colType="date" dateFormat="DD-MMM-YYYY"
        />


        <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Coverage Shape" value="#{material.coverageShape}"
                        colType="dropdown"
                        selectItems="#{ManagedBean.getMapItems('coverageShape')}">
        </pe:sheetcolumn>
</pe:sheet>
```

You can see problem on images like below
[image]

if i scroll table to right it turns

[image]

if i scroll to left it turns normal

My JSF VERSION : 2.2.1 PRİMEFACES AND PRIMEFACES EXTENSION VERSION : 6.2

Comment: Could be a bug fixed in a later HT version in a later PF Extensions?

Comment: I couldn't try with later versions. I am thinking of like frozen cells and not frozen ones not matching each other height. I fixed like no wrapping for each row but its not effective i think so